# Communication between sibling components in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Communication between parent and child](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication) components are pretty straightforward using `$broadcast` and `$dispatch`

The issue I'm trying to wrap my head around is communication between sibling components. What I currently do is run a `$dispatch` on the child which is then caught by a event on the parent `vm` which in turn is `$broadcast` to the sibling component.

IE (non-functional, simplified example):

```
new Vue({
    components: { Brother, Sister },
    events: {
        'brother-to-sister-event': function(message) {
            this.$broadcast('message-to-sister', message);
        }
});

Brother
    this.$dispatch('brother-to-sister-event', message)

Sister
    events: {
        'message-to-sister': function(message) {
            alert('Message from Brother receiced!');
        }
    }
```

I just feel like I'm doing a lot of ping pong with how my data gets passed around between the sibling components. I couldn't really find a good example in the [documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/) for handling this. The above example is my best offert to solve it.

Does anyone have a good example of how to handle this in a more efficient way? What I'm aiming for is when I `$broadcast` or `$dispatch` from Brother, this will be picked up immediately by Sister. In doing so, I don't have to clutter up the root `vm` with intermediary events.

So the solution would be something like:

```
new Vue({
    components: { Brother, Sister }
});

Brother
    this.$dispatch('brother-to-sister-event', message)

Sister
    events: {
        'brother-to-sister-event': function(message) {
            alert('Message from Brother receiced!');
        }
    }
```

But I have not managed to get something like this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain Vue.js communication of sibling components can only be done only through the parent as you are describing on your example.

A more sofisticated way to handle these cases for more complex apps is a central state manager.

Vue.js creator has published a redux like component that when used with vuejs updates their state though actions dispatched on stores. Then the 'reactiveness' of the vuejs framework picks up any changes made to the state of the component and re-renders them.

The documentation of the component is really nice
[Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)
[Vuex Documentation](http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/)
[Vuex todo mvc example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/master/examples/todomvc)

Comment: I read the first page of the Vuex documentation and it describes to be solving the exact issue that I'm facing. The fact that it is also maintained by Vue itself makes this a no-brainer. Thank you for the suggestion!